# Reset password in opmanager with postgresql on linux os

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, monitoring

Opmanager reset password.
I have been trying to log into our opmanager instance, but I have forgotten our admin password.  Is it possible to reset this?

Answer (score 0):

If the used database in MSSQL, please login to the SQL Studio, right click on OpManagerDB (CentralDB or ProbeDB in case of enterprise edition) and select Execute Query option to execute queries.

If the database used in MySQL or PgSQL, please follow the below steps :

To connect to the database directly, open Windows command prompt with "Run as Administrator" option, run the following command from \OpManager\mysql\bin or \OpManager\pgsql\bin directory :

***MySql Database - OpManager installed on Windows server
OpManager Stand alone Database:***

**OpManagerDB OpManager Central Database:**
mysql.exe -u root -P 13306 CentralDB

**OpManager Probe Database:**
mysql.exe -u root -P 13308 probeDB

**probeDB:**
mysql.exe -u root -P 13308

***PostgreSQL Database :OpManager installed on Windows server***

**OpManager Stand alone Database:**  psql -U postgres -h127.0.0.1 -p13306 OpManagerDB
**OpManager Central Database:**  psql -U postgres  -h127.0.0.1 -p13307 CentralDB 
**OpManager Probe Database:** psql -U postgres  -h127.0.0.1 -p13308 ProbeDB

Mysql Database : OpManager installed on Linux Server
OpManager Stand alone Database  mysql -u root --socket=mysql.socket -P 13306 OpManagerDB
OpManager Central Database  mysql -u root --socket=mysql.socket -P 13307 CentralDB
OpManager Probe Database    mysql -u root --socket=mysql.socket -P 13308 ProbeDB

PostgreSQL Database : OpManager installed on Linux server:
OpManager Stand alone Database  ./psql -U postgres -p -h  
Eg : ./psql -U postgres -p13306 -h localhost OpManagerDB
OpManager Central Database  ./psql -U postgres -p13307 -h localhost CentralDB
OpManager Probe Database    ./psql -U postgres -p13308 -h localhost ProbeDB